# Why is this service method not showing up?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, web-services

This is my first time programming in Visual Studio and C#. I am trying to create a web service, but my GetProduct is not showing up.

```
  namespace GettingStartedHost
 {
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public int GetProduct(int a, int b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int GetProduct(int a, int b);

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);



    }


    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }

}
```

}

When I press CTRL-F5 to start the test server, only 2 methods show up. The GetProduct does not show up. WHat is wrong?

Comment: Sample is missing definition of `IService1`...

Comment: Did you update the service reference in the client project?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can't seem to get it owrking

Comment: You would have to address my name for your response to show up in my inbox ;) What I mean is: Have you right-clicked your service reference in your client project and hit `Update Service Reference`?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code.

```
namespace GettingStartedHost
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public int GetProduct(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int GetProduct(int a, int b);

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Alan : In your code you have `Service1 : IService1` but your interface code have `IService` you are missing `1`.

Comment: Hello Jams, thanks ofr the help. I am getting "The namespace already contains a definition for IService1"  It's still not working :(